# passing data through Angular custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created a custom directive in angular. I would like to pass parent data through the directive using scope but I'm getting 'undefined' when I log scope and scope.questionId.

**HTML**

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" my-directive="" on-flag="someFunction" question-id="question">Flag</a>
```

**Angular Directive**

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      onFlag: '&onFlag',
      questionId: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.click(function() {
        console.log(scope);
        console.log(scope.questionId);
        return;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Try logging `attrs.onFlag` and `attrs.questionId`

Comment: i got onFlag() for logging attrs.onFlag and still undefined for attrs.questionId

Comment: why you returning `element.click` function, what you are trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wrnxqvm8/

Comment: @Jason, where do you define `someFunction` and `question` ?

Comment: @PankajParkar sorry that was a typo, i've fixed it.

Comment: @mparnisari not sure why it alerts 'question' in fiddle but still alert as 'undefined' when running the actual app

Comment: @Maximus someFunction is a function defined inside of the controller and question is data being passed into directive

Comment: I solved the issue, I have three similar element on my html page and I've been testing on the wrong one, so not getting the correct response. sorry for the confusion and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

**elem.bind**:- It uses the JQLite which is lite version of JQuery. Here we are writing the code to handle the click event performed on the directive.
It is same like JQuery $("class or id").click(). (I hope this explains is sufficient)

```html
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      onFlag: '&onFlag',
      questionId: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
       elem.bind('click', function() {
         console.log(scope.questionId);
      });
    }
  };
});
```